# QWebView displays different effects on different computers

Tags: linux, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview

I have a QtWebKit program, using QWebView. I have different versions of Qt in Qt Creator :

- 5.3.1
- 5.2.1
- 4.8

When I use 5.3.1 to compile the program, the html part will display the right effect in my computer, but when I use 5.2.1 or 4.8 to compile, the effect is not the same as the one set in the CSS file.

When I run the 5.3.1 binary on another computer, it will display the wrong effect, like the one when I compile with 5.2.1. I used `dpkg -l | grep webkit` and set the same library version on two computers, but I also got the wrong effect.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Add a minimal code example showing the problem. are your sure that's it's actually using 5.3.1 on the other computer? It might load a system-wide installed 5.2 or something)

Comment: both computer has qt 5.3.1 ,   the binary compiled in my computer doesnt work well in other computer.  and other computer 's banary doesnt work well in my computer, i think they are  normal html code with css .